# Access Parent functions/variables from a child class in Python

Tags: python, pyside2, maya-api

I´m currently trying to play around with Python and QT to create some tools for Maya (3D Application).

So far I´m getting along, but have now some issues and getting my head around inheritance. I created a child class of QListWidgetItem to add some custom logic and wanted to access this logic at a later point when iterating over the left QListWidget.

[image: My UI]

```
# Widget to get displayed inside myQListWidget
class BaseModule(QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem):
   def __init__(self,name):
      super(BaseModule, self).__init__(parent=parent)
         self.setText(name)
         self.name = name

   def BuildSkeleton(self):
      # Do some magic in here

window = belt.TWToolbelt()
rootModule = BaseModule(name='Root')
window.ui.AllModules.addItem(rootModule)

model = window.ui.ActiveModules.model()
model.rowsInserted.connect(lambda *_:drop(window))

# function, which get`s executed after a drag&drop action    
def drop(window):
   items = []
   for index in xrange(window.ui.ActiveModules.count()):
      items.append(window.ui.ActiveModules.item(index))

   for item in items:
      # iterating over all Active Modes on the left to execute my custom logic
      # as item is a QtWidget.QListWidgetItem and the fucntion is only existing
      # in it`s child class BaseModule I would like to know, how I can access or cast from a 
      # ParentClass to it`s child class, so I can execute my function
      item.BuildSkeleton()
```

I get following error with that code:

```
 AttributeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem' object has no attribute 'BuildSkeleton'
```

Hopefully you can help me out.

Thank you in advance

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: what is your question? what is your problem?

Comment: It's really hard to answer a question when we don't know what the problem is.  From my perspective, I see nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: The problem is that at least some of the items are not BaseModule but QListWidgetIem, and therefore do not have the BuildSkeleton method, which is what indicates the error. How do you add the items? Inheritance inherits properties from the parent class to the child classes, not vice versa as it seems you think.

Comment: AttributeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem' object has no attribute 'BuildSkeleton' ... get this error when trying my code above, as my BaseModule kinda get downcasted to a QListWidgetItem ... so how can I "upcast" it, so I can access it`s attributes again.

Comment: I add them with following method: window.ui.AllModules.addItem(rootModule)

Comment: @cFx Okay, but that's only for the "Root" item, and the other items: "Spine", "Leg" and "Arm"? Please use `@username`

Comment: @cFx There is no concept of "upcast" since the parent class does not have the properties of the child classes, but the "downcast" is possible because the daughter classes do have the properties of the parent class.

Comment: @eyllanesc I add them the same way (just made the code smaller).

Comment: @cFx We want a [mre] as they pointed out in the first comment, and clearly a piece of code is not. So if you want help provide the MRE since in your current code there are many hidden things.

Comment: @eyllanesc I instantiated the object as a BaseModule, duo of the functions it kinda get`s downcasted to its parent class QListWidget. But isn`t there any way existing to get the reference to the "instantiated" object.  Will do an minimal reproducible example

Comment: @cFx mmm, in python there is no casting, here the objects of the BaseModule class will always be of the BaseModule class unlike other languages such as C++ or java, so in your case I suppose you have n items where some are BaseModule and others QListWidget by what the method BuildSkeleton it will only work in the first one for that reason in my previous comment I indicate to you that you do a verification, have you tried it?

Comment: @cFx use `if isinstance(item, BaseModule): item.BuildSkeleton()`

Comment: @eyllanesc I kinda have some C++ background, so that might be the point. All objects are BaseModules, so my complete List get`s filled with "BaseModules", but as the QT function wants to have QTWidgetItem, I`ve created that child class. So I don`t have a verification.

Comment: @cFx mmm, if you are using python you should forget about C++ since although they share many features in the case of "casting" it does not exist.